# Force youtube advert to appear for testing

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am developing an `Android youtube-api` based application.

I would like to test the application when an advertisement shows.

There is an event called `onAdStarted` defined in `YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener`.

Is there a way to force an advertisement to always appear?

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out regarding this? I'm in the same boat looking to always force youtube advertisements to appear before a video for testing purposes.

Comment: Sorry, never found a solution for this.